# Changing between tabs using a Singleton class causes SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sigabrt

I come from more of an Android development background so apologies if this is a stupid question, but it's just wracking my brain and I can't see what is wrong. I have a Singleton Class implementation as follows:

Header file:

```
@interface SingletonClass : NSObject
{
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;

+ (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance;
- (id) init;
- (void)setCategory: (NSMutableArray *) x;
- (NSMutableArray *)getCategory;

@end
```

Class Implementation:

```
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@implementation SingletonClass
@synthesize categoryArray;


static SingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (SingletonClass *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    return [self sharedInstance];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

- (void)setCategory: (NSMutableArray *)category_array{
    categoryArray = category_array;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getCategory{
    return categoryArray;
}

@end
```

I have 2 Tabs each of which I try to access the Singleton Object which holds the Arrays I need using:

```
SingletonClass* myapp = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];
categories = [myapp getCategory];
```

When switching tabs it works when the Singleton Object is not called, but as soon as I use it I get the SIGABRT error. (Think it's a memory warning). Are Singleton Instances not sharable across Tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, singletons may certainly be shared across tabs.

a) If you're not using ARC, then your reference counting is off.

b) This sounds like a reference counting offset (can happen with ARC, MRC or GC). There is a diagnostic mode "Enable Zombies". Basically, it means that objects are not actually deallocated and 'zombified' when their reference count reaches zero. A zombified object will then note an error whenever it is messaged. You can use this and record reference counts for objects using the Zombies instrument in Instruments.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using ARC so just concentrating on your point b, I have tried the Zombies Instrument with Zombies enabled but nothing was flagged I just get the same error, no console output it just says gbd, XCode jumps to the main.m class and displays the SIGABRT error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show more code from the method that calls the Singleton?
Also some more Console output would be helpful.

My guess is, that category_Array is a dangling pointer as the original categoryArray has already been released.

A retain setter ("setCategory:" method) should retain it's new value and release the old one.

Comment: That's basically it for the method that calles the Singleton and there is no console output only gbd. When I try to change tab XCode jumps to the main.m class and displays the SIGABRT error. I am using ARC so can't call retain on the objects created. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Ah, I was irritated as you use retain in the property instead of strong.

So I thought you wouldn't use ARC.

Comment: Oh that's my bad, I still get the same issues as before even with it changed to strong instead of retain.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say thank you to those that tried to help me, the problem I was having is really trivial. I have the app flow created using the storyboard and had the wrong CellIdentifier set so would throw the memory error.